# Python: Better way to take every letter/number/etc. from a string and convert it into a list?

Tags: python

I actually know how to do this using `loop`, but the code looks too ugly :-(. So I would like to ask some better methods.

E.g. I have a string:

```
a = "123 456 7sr"
```

I want to convert every number/letter/empty space/etc into a list. The desired result should be like:

```
["1", "2", "3", " ", "4", "5", "6", " ", "7", "s", "r"]
```

Is there some other methods? (Please not the methods using the `for/while loop`)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can use `list(a)`

Comment: Thank you! so easy is it! @umutto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straightforward approach that works everywhere is to call `list`'s constructor, which converts any iterable (and `str` are iterables of their characters) to a `list` of the values produced by iterating:

```
list(a)
```

On Python 3.5+ with [additional unpacking generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), you can alternatively do:

```
[*a]
```

which is equivalent to `list(a)`, except it doesn't need to look up and call the `list` constructor through generalized function call semantics (making it slightly faster and rendering it immune to accidental behavioral changes if `list` is name shadowed, e.g. because someone did something terrible like `list = [1,2,3]`).

All other approaches (e.g. no-op list comprehensions) are slower, uglier versions of these two.

Comment: Great! Thanks! It was me who sometimes did list = [1,2,3] :-)

Answer (score 4):

That's simply:

```
>>> a = "123 456 7sr"
>>> list(a)
['1', '2', '3', ' ', '4', '5', '6', ' ', '7', 's', 'r']
```

Answer (score 2):

This might not be better, but an alternative approach would be to use a list comprehension:

```
a = "123 456 7sr"
print([e for e in a])
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3', ' ', '4', '5', '6', ' ', '7', 's', 'r']
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are iteratable elements so pass the iteratable to the list's constructor then it will return a list.

```
>>a="123 456 7sr"
>>a=list(a)
>>print(a)
>>['1', '2', '3', ' ', '4', '5', '6', ' ', '7', 's', 'r']
>>print(type(a))
>>list
```

Comment: Use of iteratables  are the best ways to do it rather than using the loops.